# Perl index function to extract a certain substring

Tags: perl

Given a certain sequence A stored in an array, I have to find if a larger sequence B contains sequence A.

I am stuck at the index part... and i'm getting an error that argument *"TGACCA"* isn't numeric in array element in line *69* which is:

`if (index($record_r1[1], $r2_seq[$check]) != -1)`

---

The code is:

```
foreach my $check (@r2_seq)
{
  if (index($record_r1[1], $r2_seq[$check]) != -1)
  {
     $matches= $matches + 1;
     print "Matched";
  }
  else
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach my $check (@r2_seq)
```

`$check` takes on the value of each element in `@r2_seq`.  It is not the index.

```
$r2_seq[$check]
```

This is attempting to use an element of `@r2_seq` as the index into `@r2_seq`.  It is unlikely what you want.  More probably, you want to use

```
$check
```

as in

```
if (index($record_r1[1], $check) != -1)
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted `$check` to be **index**, so then use the following code:

```
foreach my $index (0..$#r2_seq)
{
  if (index($record_r1[1], $r2_seq[$index]) != -1)
  {
     $matches= $matches + 1;
     print "Matched";
  }
  else
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't go to the match even though the substring is there.